# Eclipse won't run on fresh windows 10

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8, windows-10

I downloaded and installed latest jre and jdk and I can't run **eclipse (mars)**.

These are exact versions I have installed and part of log file from configure folder:

**jre-8u60-windows-x64.exe**

**jdk-8u60-windows-x64.exe**

**eclipse-jee-mars-R-win32-x86_64.zip**

I'm running windows 10 x64 OS.

```
!SESSION 2015-09-17 11:54:25.321 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.5.0.I20150603-2000
java.version=1.8.0_60
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ant.ui 4 0 2015-09-17 11:54:26.090
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.ant.ui [80]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui.editors; bundle-version="[3.2.0,4.0.0)"; resolution:="optional"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.ui.editors; bundle-version="3.9.0.v20150213-1939"; singleton:="true"
       org.eclipse.ui.editors [758]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui.ide; bundle-version="[3.5.0,4.0.0)"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.ui.ide; bundle-version="3.11.0.v20150510-1749"; singleton:="true"
              org.eclipse.ui.ide [761]
                Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine; bundle-version="[2.0.0,3.0.0)"
                  -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine; bundle-version="2.4.0.v20150511-1532"; singleton:="true"
                     org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine [332]
                       Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.io
                         -> Export-Package: org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.io; bundle-symbolic-name="org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository"; bundle-version="1.2.200.v20150428-1613"; version="0.0.0"; x-friends:="org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine"
                            org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository [337]
                              Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.persistence
                                -> Export-Package: org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.persistence; bundle-symbolic-name="org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository"; bundle-version="2.3.100.v20150428-1613"; version="0.0.0"; x-friends:="org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository,  org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine,  org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository,  org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.importexport,  org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository.tools"
                                   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository [342]
                                     Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.eclipse.equinox.security.storage
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui.externaltools; bundle-version="[3.2.0,4.0.0)"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.ui.externaltools; bundle-version="3.3.0.v20150302-1002"; singleton:="true"
       org.eclipse.ui.externaltools [759]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui.ide; bundle-version="[3.2.0,4.0.0)"; resolution:="optional"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.ui.ide; bundle-version="3.11.0.v20150510-1749"; singleton:="true"
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.debug.ui; bundle-version="[3.10.0,4.0.0)"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.debug.ui; bundle-version="3.11.0.v20150514-0917"; singleton:="true"
              org.eclipse.debug.ui [233]
                Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui.ide; bundle-version="[3.5.0,4.0.0)"
                  -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.ui.ide; bundle-version="3.11.0.v20150510-1749"; singleton:="true"
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui.ide; bundle-version="[3.2.0,4.0.0)"; resolution:="optional"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.ui.ide; bundle-version="3.11.0.v20150510-1749"; singleton:="true"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:434)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1561)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1533)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.compare 4 0 2015-09-17 11:54:26.097
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.compare [84]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui.ide; bundle-version="[3.3.0,4.0.0)"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.ui.ide; bundle-version="3.11.0.v20150510-1749"; singleton:="true"
       org.eclipse.ui.ide [761]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine; bundle-version="[2.0.0,3.0.0)"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine; bundle-version="2.4.0.v20150511-1532"; singleton:="true"
              org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine [332]
                Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.io
                  -> Export-Package: org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.io; bundle-symbolic-name="org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository"; bundle-version="1.2.200.v20150428-1613"; version="0.0.0"; x-friends:="org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine"
                     org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository [337]
                       Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.persistence
                         -> Export-Package: org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.persistence; bundle-symbolic-name="org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository"; bundle-version="2.3.100.v20150428-1613"; version="0.0.0"; x-friends:="org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository,  org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine,  org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository,  org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.importexport,  org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository.tools"
                            org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository [342]
                              Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.eclipse.equinox.security.storage

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:434)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1561)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1533)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at      org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
```

Comment: Did you try running as administrator?

Comment: Yes. I also tried reinstalling jre and jdk, but still it's not working

Comment: Have you checked that your PATH variable is pointing to the correct jdk?

Comment: Yes. It's path in the ProgramData to the symbolic link. I tried deleting that and using -vm flag in eclipse.ini and also deleting it and replacing it with real path in Program Files folders.

Comment: @MikeJackson : can you try `-clean` in **eclipse.ini** on First Line and try to run again.

Comment: Tried with -clean and I got same errors in log file

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a problem, but not solution... yet!

These files are missing from plugins dir!

> org.eclipse.rse.dstore.security_3.0.400.201403100950.jar
> org.eclipse.jetty.security_9.2.9.v20150224.jar
>
> org.eclipse.equinox.security_1.2.100.v20150423-1356.jar
> org.eclipse.equinox.security.win32.x86_64_1.0.100.v20130327-1442.jar
> org.eclipse.equinox.security.ui_1.1.200.v20130626-2037.jar

Windows' winzip silently doesn't extract these files.

WinRar reports error permission denied: at first I get standard pop-up "this action needs admin rights" with Continue and cancel buttons. When I click Continue, I get permission denied and pop-up with Try Again button. When I manually try to copy these files from winrar's temp dir, I get same Permission Denied pop-up.

It seems like once WinRar unpacked these files, you can't do anything with them.

I also tried from CMD takeown /F, but no results

Comment: Do you have a virus scanner running ?

Comment: Do you right click the ZIP file, go to Security, then press UNLOCK?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce You mean UNBLOCK? I did that on zip and it didn't work. What did work however was, right clicking each of these 5 files separately, going under Security tab, manually adding my windows user into "Group or user names:" (which was empty) and finally checking "Full control" under permissions below. You can go ahead and write that in new answer so I can tag it as Correct. Thank you sir.

Comment: It's also unknown to me, why 'takeown /F' didn't work, when I got SUCCESS in cmd after using it?(I didn't even have copy rights)

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue as reported. I think the problem is to do with Windows' winzip not extracting the files correctly. (Could be due to the extremely long file names used in Eclipse, but can't be sure).

I extracted the same file using WinRar and Eclipse worked as expected.

Size on disk: **341 MB**

Contains: **5,110 Files, 1,224 Folders**

ENV:
Windows 10 pro (64-bit)
eclipse-jee-mars-1-win32-x86_64.zip
java version "1.7.0_51"

Answer (score -2):

I installed today (7th Nov 2015) onto a fairly recent & clean Windows 10 x64 without the issues described above, so this may have been sorted out in later installers.

I used the oomph installer, and installed jre-8u66-windows-x64.exe prior to running the Eclipse install.

The files that Mike mentions are all present in my folder:
C:\Users\xxxx.p2\pool\plugins

Andy

Comment: This is the equivalent of "it works for me", and doesn't answer the question of why it isn't working for the OP.